# How to convert this jQuery to function component or class component or react hooks

Tags: jquery, react-hooks

How to convert this jQuery to function component or class component or react hooks

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if($('#DIV_ID').children().length === 0) {
            grecaptcha.render('DIV_ID', {
                'sitekey' : 'YOUR_SITE_KEY', 
                'callback' : recaptchaCallback
            });
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to reference the element and register the 500ms delay in an *on-mount* effect hook

```jsx
const recaptchaCallback = (token) => {
  // whatever
};

const Captcha = () => {
  const divRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      grecaptcha.render(divRef.current, {
        sitekey: "YOUR_SITE_KEY",
        callback: recaptchaCallback,
      });
    }, 500);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div ref={divRef}></div>;
};
```